# C++ creating a copy constructor for a class with a reference member variable

Tags: c++, reference, copy-constructor

I have a class `ModelRecorder` with contains a reference `modelRef_` to another class OpModel.

```
class ModelRecorder : public CompositionalModel //This is an abstract base class
{

    OpModel& modelRef_;
};
```

When an instance of `ModelRecorder` is created and `modelRef_` is initalized. Thats fine I unerstand that.

How would I write a copy constructor for `ModelRecorder` so that if another instance is created, the reference memeber `modelRef_` will be initalized with the previous created OpModel object?

Note that `CompositionalModel` is an abstract base class.

In another class there is fucntion that returns a reference to `CompositionalModel` he base class. I understand returning the narrower base class is a good OOP.

For example `CompositionalModel& recordedModel();`

I want to pass this reference to the base class to the copy constructor.

I tried this but it gives the error, which is correct `modelRef` is in the dereived class `ModelRecorder`.

error: ‘const class mv::CompositionalModel’ has no member named ‘modelRef_

```
mv::ModelRecorder::ModelRecorder(const CompositionalModel& arg) : CompositionalModel{static_cast<const ModelRecorder&>(arg)}, modelRef_{arg.modelRef_}
{
}
```

Comment: This is what does the default copy constructor for references. Nothing to do. Unless there's something fishy about what you mean by _the reference memeber modelRef_ will be initalized with the previous created OpModel object_. [mcve] please.

Comment: `ModelRecorder(const ModelRecorder&) = default` will do it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

The first way - make compiler do it for you:

```
ModelRecorder(const ModelRecorder&) = default;
```

The second way - implement it yourself:

```
ModelRecorder(const ModelRecorder& arg)
    :CompositionalModel{arg}, modelRef_{arg.modelRef_} {}
```

Note that you *have to* use the member initializer list, since we're dealing with references. The difference between the above code and this:

```
ModelRecorder(const ModelRecorder& arg) 
    :CompositionalModel{arg} {
    modelRef_ = arg.modelRef_;
}
```

is that the later *does not initialize the reference*. It violates the rules, since references must be initialized, not assigned later. My best advice is to stick with the easy way, since it's the least possible to mess up using it

Comment: The second and third version do not call the base class copy constructor, you want to add this. See Item 12 ("Copy all parts of an object") in Effective C++, 3rd edition.

Comment: My bad, overlooked the fact `ModelRecorder` inherits from `CompositionalModel`. Thank you for pointing that out, sir.

Comment: You're welcome, it's always rewarding and fun to throw Scott Meyers items at users :P

Comment: @Fureeish thank you - what if you wanted to pass a reference to a base class `CompositionalModel` to the copy constructor? A different part of the program returns a reference to `CompositionalModel`. I understand returning a reference to the narrower base class is good OOP.

Comment: @pelicanbrady Then it's not longer a copy constructor. Regardless, a [MCVE] of your situation would really help in providing good answers.

Comment: @Max Langhof ah I thought so. The program is quite large but  I have amended my question to include as much details as possible. I sorry for causing confusion I thought I required a copy constructor.

Comment: @pelicanbrady This is a pretty different question now (and runs into its own issue that I would like to detail). It also still does not show the relation between `OpModel` and the other two models. Would you mind asking a new question instead, so that this question+answer are not invalidated?

Comment: @Max Langhof - sure no problem.